# How to avoid NA while summing variables through `mutate()` in the Tidyverse?

Tags: r, tidyverse, na, dplyr

I am trying to sum lots of variables for creating a new variable. There are `NA`'s in some of them and I need to avoid `NA`'s because the outcome for every row with any `NA` is another `NA`:

```
library(tidyverse)
v1 <- c(NA, 2, 3)
v2 <- c(1, 3, 5)
datos <- tibble(v1, v2)

datos %>%
  mutate(v3 = v1 + v2)
```

The outcome of this script is a vector `NA 5 8`, what is needed as outcome is the variable `1 5 8`. I would like to know if is it mandatory replacing `NA`'s for zeros, which I would prefer not to.

Comment: `rowSums(datos, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: I'd do `datos %>% rowwise %>% mutate(v3 = sum(c_across(v1:v2), na.rm = TRUE))`, gives you flexibility to play with desired column names/indices to be included in the sum